# Is there a way to export the layers separately from the picture that captured with dual cameras and contained depth data?

Tags: avfoundation, ios11, depth, iphone-8-plus

I am new to the community and working on an experiment to extract depth map images from iPhone 8+.

Is there a way to export/capture the layers separately from the picture that captured with dual cameras and contained depth data?

I would like to access the closest layer as image object for later proccesses. And I don't know how to identify and extract a specifit layer from the image with depth data.

I tried to look into the documentations and the sample code but didn't find a way to do so. May be I am not digging deep enough.

It will also be a great help if any body can point me into the right direction.